# How find this equation $n!+(n+1)!+\cdots+(n+m)!=a^b$ all solutions

Tags: number-theory

Find all natural numbers $m,n$ and positive integer $a,b>1$, such
$$n!+(n+1)!+\cdots+(n+m)!=a^b$$

I find

> (1):$$1!+2!+3!=1+2+6=9=3^2$$
>   then
>   $$n=1,m=2,a=3,b=2$$

Now @Xoff have found other two solution

> (2):$$2!+3!=8=2^3$$
>   so
>   $$n=1,m=1,a=2,b=3$$
>
> (3):$$2!+3!+4!=32=2^5$$
>   so
>   $$n=2,m=2,a=2,b=5$$

and Now  Peter Košinár Found the fourth solution

> (4):$$4!+5!=12^2$$
>   so
>   $$n=4,m=1,a=12,b=2$$

so I only find this,I think this have other,so How can find all solution,Thank you

This problem is my student ask me,so　I don't kown come from

Thank you

@Ivan Loh  and so on can see this nice problem

Oh,my student tell me this problem is  from china BBS:http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2760536313

Today I have solve follow problem:

if $x,y,z\in Z$,such
$$1!+2!+3!+\cdots+x!=y^z$$
have only four case
(1):$$x=1,y=\pm 1,z=2n$$
(2):$$x=3,y=\pm 3,z=2$$
(3):$$x\in Z,z=1,y=1+2!+\cdots+x!$$
(4):$$x=1,y=1,z\ge 3,z=2n+1$$

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: $n+m=3,n=1,m=2.$

Comment: You have others : $2!+3!=8=2^3$ and $2!+3!+4!=32=2^5$

Comment: ... and, of course, $4! + 5! = 12^2$

Comment: And if I did not make any (programming) mistake, there is no other solution for $m+n<22$.

Comment: @Xoff Arbitrary precision?

Comment: @chubakueno exact computation ? yes, of course. The main problem is factorization that takes a lots of time.

Comment: In fact, only partial factorization is needed. So I verified up to $n+m<400$, and there is no solution. One exception (!!) : for $n=2$, $m=20$, I can't seem to get an easy factorization, so I did verify by hand that particular case : $1177652997443428940312=8\times147206624680428617539$ but it's not a cube.

Comment: The problematic case is $n=2$ and $m=21$, sorry. But it's the same way to solve it by hand. Anyway, I would be surprise now if there was any more solutions than the previous four.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure why one would ask such a question, but I suspect it might be pretty hard to solve it completely (or maybe not!). On the other hand, it is not difficult to show, for example, that there is only the one known solution with, say, $n > m^2$, by noting that $n!$ divides the left-hand-side and that each prime between $n/2$ and $n$ divides $n!$ exactly once. The product of such primes is roughly of size $e^{n/2}$ which (under the assumption that $n > m^2$) is greater than 
$$
\left( n! + (n+1)! + \cdots + (n+m)! \right)/n!.
$$
This ensures that there is some prime between $n/2$ and $n$ which divides $a^b$ exactly once, contradicting $b > 1$. There are some details required to make this argument explicit, but none of them are too unpleasant.